# Use Meraki to send push push notifications to the app

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am developing an iOS app for a client which is Meraki controlled. The Meraki solution is controlled by the client, I just ship the ipa file via a plist file.

Now I want to add push notifications as an enhancement to the app. As Meraki works based on push notifications ([Meraki Push Notification](https://documentation.meraki.com/SM/Device_Enrollment/Renewing_an_Apple_MDM_Push_Certificate)), I was wondering if I can actually use it to send app related push notifications?

So can I ask for the p12 file of the client, deploy it on our server and send push notifications on API calls (e.g. [C# push notifications IIS](http://blog.mdisoft.com/post/10736697438/apple-push-notifications-apns-with-net-c-and)) which would spare me using a third party provider or my own push service?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Meraki AP's Bluetooth Beacon if you have a model MR32/42/52/53/72. This sends a message directly to the mobile app. You'll need the mobile app to have the Apple iBeacon service running.

You can also use Meraki's CMX Location API to detect a device's MAC address. It sends an HTTP post to your server. You'll need a server to host a listener, but fortunately ciscoshipped.io will host it for free.

developers.meraki.com